# Entity Collection Property is Empty when Loading from RavenDB

Tags: c#, ravendb

I started using RavenDB today. When I save a class, I can see the Collection property in the DB:

[image]

However, when I load the class, the collection has no items in it:

```
public IEnumerable<CustomVariableGroup> GetAll()
{
    using (IDocumentSession session = Database.OpenSession())
    {
        IEnumerable<CustomVariableGroup> groups = session.Query<CustomVariableGroup>();
        return groups;
    }
}
```

[image]

Is there some type of activation depth that needs to be set in order to see the properties that are POCOs?

Edit (to show the classes, by request):

```
public class EntityBase : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
  public string Id { get; set; }  // Required field for all objects with RavenDB.
}

    public class CustomVariableGroup : EntityBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<CustomVariable> _customVariables;       

    public ObservableCollection<CustomVariable> CustomVariables
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._customVariables == null)
            {
                this._customVariables = new ObservableCollection<CustomVariable>();
            }
            return this._customVariables;
        }
    }
}

    public class CustomVariable : EntityBase
{
    private string _key;
    private string _value;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The key.
    /// </value>
    public string Key
    {
        get { return this._key; }

        set
        {
            this._key = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(() => this.Key);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The value.
    /// </value>
    public string Value
    {
        get { return this._value; }

        set
        {
            this._value = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(() => this.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It should work out of the box. Can you show your classes?

Comment: @Daniel: I added the classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it. There was no setter on the CustomVariables property. As soon as I added the private setter, it worked. So, apparently RavenDB doesn't use the private backing field, like db4o does. RavenDB needs the property.

```
public ObservableCollection<CustomVariable> CustomVariables
{
    get
    {
        if (this._customVariables == null)
        {
            this._customVariables = new ObservableCollection<CustomVariable>();
        }
        return this._customVariables;
    }

    private set
    {
        this._customVariables = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this was why I asked for the classes. :-) Btw, you can check this as your answer, so that others know you've already found one.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. I'll check this as the answer, but I have to wait two days to accept my own answer. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the query was executed? Try `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()`:

```cs
public IEnumerable<CustomVariableGroup> GetAll()
{
    using (IDocumentSession session = Database.OpenSession())
    {
        IEnumerable<CustomVariableGroup> groups = session.Query<CustomVariableGroup>();
        return groups.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes it was executed. If you see the screenshot of the debugging session, you'll see that the Name property has a value. And in my UI, I see the name but not the CustomVariables property. This is actually working for me with a different class that has a collection property. So I need to see what the difference is. Thanks!

Comment: As a side note, opening and closing the session inside a single method is considered to be a bad idea. You aren't letting the session a chance to do its optimizations.

Comment: What is the scope of the session? The RavenDB web site has this: "DocumentStore should be created once per application and stored as a singleton." I did that. Then the site shows an example of a session within a using block, and I assumed that each DB call/unit of work would be within this session construct. No?

Comment: You're right Bob. The DocumentStore is best implemented as Singleton once per Application. In a web application this will probably be inside your global.asax. The scope of a Session is in almost all cases the unit-of-work, that means the begin and the end of a request in a web-application. In a windows-applications it's basically the duration of an application UoW but should not span across multiple user actions. In your sample the session seems to be to short since it lives inside a method "GetAll".

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. I actually worked through this and posted my solution in another post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668774/ravendb-useoptimisticconcurrency-in-config/8669855#8669855. I'm getting there...