# RavenDB - One client can't see changes from a different client

Tags: ravendb

I'm running two instances of my application. In one instance, I save one of my entities. When I check the RavenDB (http://localhost:8080/raven), I can see the change. Then, in my other client, I do this (below), but I don't see the changes from the other application. What do I need to do in order to get the most recent data in the DB?

```cs
public IEnumerable<CustomVariableGroup> GetAll()
{
    return Session
        .Query<CustomVariableGroup>()
        .Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResults());
}
```

Edit: The code above works if I try to make a change and get a concurrency exception. After that, when I call refresh (which invokes the above code), it works.

Here is the code that does the save:

```cs
public void Save<T>(T objectToSave)
{
    Guid eTag = (Guid)Session.Advanced.GetEtagFor(objectToSave);
    Session.Store(objectToSave, eTag);
    Session.SaveChanges();
}
```

And here is the class that contains the Database and Session:

```cs
public abstract class DataAccessLayerBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the database.
    /// </summary>
    protected static DocumentStore Database { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the session.
    /// </summary>
    protected static IDocumentSession Session { get; private set; }

    static DataAccessLayerBase()
    {
        if (Database != null) { return; }

        Database = GetDatabase();
        Session = GetSession();
    }        

    private static DocumentStore GetDatabase()
    {
        string databaseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["databaseUrl"];            

        DocumentStore documentStore = new DocumentStore();

        try
        {
            //documentStore.ConnectionStringName = "RavenDb";  // See app.config for why this is commented.
            documentStore.Url = databaseUrl;
            documentStore.Initialize();
        }
        catch
        {
            documentStore.Dispose();
            throw;
        }

        return documentStore;
    }

    private static IDocumentSession GetSession()
    {
        IDocumentSession session = Database.OpenSession();

        session.Advanced.UseOptimisticConcurrency = true;

        return session;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lacking more detailed information and some code, I can only guess...

Please make sure that you call `.SaveChanges()` on your session. Without explicitly specifiying an ITransaction your IDocumentSession will be isolated and transactional between it's opening and the call to `.SaveChanges`. Either all operations succeed or none. But if you don't call it all your previous `.Store` calls will be lost.

If I was wrong, please post more details about your code.

**EDIT: Second answer (after additional information):**

Your problem has to do with the way RavenDB caches on the client-side. RavenDB by default caches every GET request throughout a DocumentSession. Plain queries are just GET queries (and no, it has nothing to do wheter your index in dynamic or manually defined upfront) and therefore they will be cached. The solution in your application is to dispose the session and open a new one.

I suggest you rethink your Session lifecycle. It seems that your sessions live too long, otherwise this concurrency wouldn't be an issue. If you're building a web-application I recommend to open and close the session with the beginning and the end of your request. Have a look at RaccoonBlog to see it implemented elegantly.

Comment: I added the code, above, that does the Save(). Does that help?

Comment: I should also note that I have not added any indexes. I'm not sure if that matters, but RavenDB seems to added indexes automatically. I don't know if manually adding them is an old thing, or if it's still relevant.

Comment: Bob, you don't need to manually add the indexes. RavenDB evaluates your query and creates a dynamic index that can provide an answer to your question (query). If they are used very often RavenDB will auto-optimize itself and promote the index to be permanent and saved to disk. You only need to add very complex indexes manually. Please see my edit above to answer your original question.

Comment: I'll try that; I bet that's the answer. But I'm actually now confused about what the lifetime of a Session should be. On this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661968/entity-collection-property-is-empty-when-loading-from-ravendb/8662524#8662524), Ayende says having a session live for only one method is too short. So I changed it to start the session when the app started, and close when the app closed. Now I have this problem of not seeing changes from another client. If a method is too short for a Session, and the lifetime of an app is too long, what's right?

Comment: To follow up on my last comment... The unit of work is really getting the list of items, which mean the session should only span that one method. If it's supposed to last longer than that, what are the guidelines for how long it should live?

Comment: Ok, now I remember why I moved from Sessions in a method to one Session for an app. If I close the Session after each method, then this doesn't work:
Guid eTag = (Guid)Session.Advanced.GetEtagFor(objectToSave);
So I really do need the session for the lifetime of the app. When the user opens this simple UI, it displays the info in a grid and needs to update the DB as the user makes changes. If I close the Session, I lose the ability to get eTags and therefore the ability to do optimistic concurrency. Now I'm just not sure what to do. Maybe just take a break for a bit...

Comment: Look at the link Ayende posted below. Session Management is basically the same as with NHibernate. Maybe that helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Bob,
It looks like you have but a single session in the application, which isn't right. The following article talks about NHibernate, but the session management parts applies to RavenDB as well:

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mag200912NHibernate

This code is meaningless:

```cs
Guid eTag = (Guid)Session.Advanced.GetEtagFor(objectToSave);
Session.Store(objectToSave, eTag);
```

It basically a no op, but one that looks important. You seems to be trying to work with a model where you have to manually manage all the saves, don't do that. You only need to manage things yourself when you create a new item, that is all.

As for the reason you get this problem, here is a sample:

```cs
var session = documentStore.OpenSession();
var post1 = session.Load<Post>(1);
// change the post by another client
post2 = session.Load<Post>(1); // will NOT go to the server, will give the same instance as post1

Assert.ReferenceEquals(post1,post2);
```

Sessions are short lived, and typically used in the scope of a single form / request.

Comment: Ok, I'm reading that link now. If sessions are short-lived, and in the scope of a single form, what if my form is open for the entire life of the app? Indeed, when the user opens this UI dashboard utility, that's all there is to the app; the form/window to manage the data. So if a method is too short of a lifetime for the session, and the entire app too long... ya know? Ok, I'll see if that link helps. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Bob, it's all the same with NHibernates Session or Entity Frameworks ObjectContext. Same rules apply there - if you need shorter lifetime due to expected cache issues, then just recreate your form more often. It's just that easy.